# SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On: RealyState is not present in the request.

Tags: wso2, wso2-stratos

I am setting up WSO2 Stratos server locally. It seems everything is configured properly as per mentioned in README file.

If I click on Sign In button it redirect me to samlsso page:
https://stratos-local.wso2.com:9444/samlsso which shows following information on the page:

SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
RealyState is not present in the request.
This request will not be processed further.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please send a query string parameter "RelayState", for example,

query string should be like "RelayState=somevalue&SAMLRequest=request"

If you are not willing to use the RelayState parameter, just pass a random value.

However, this behaviour will be changed in the next WSO2 Identity Server release 4.5.0 which is due on July. In that, the relay state is no longer mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for information. It is resolved by running elb server. It is working fine now. I have mentioned all the steps [here](http://sunnydyal.wordpress.com/)